# Change Enum.map from Elixir to Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to convert Elixir function into Erlang function:
In Elixir I have:

```
Enum.map(0..n, fn i-> fun(i) end)
```

And I need to re-write to Erlang.

Any Idea? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erlang doesn't have a single generic function that can handle mapping over any data structure like `Enum.map` in Elixir. The simplest way to do this would be to use `lists:seq` to generate the list and `lists:map`:

```
1> lists:map(fun(X) -> X * X end, lists:seq(0, 10)).
[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehensions:

```
[ F(X) || X <- lists:seq(0, 10) ].
```

aka

```
[ X*X || X <- lists:seq(0, 10) ].
```